# Convert yard with grass into vegetable garden

Tags: vegetables, grass, urban-gardening

I want to convert my backyard into a vegetable garden. The area consists of mostly patchy grass and some weeds. The plantable area has plenty of sunlight. The sod is 3 inches deep. I want to plant seeds immediately. I live in central New Jersey.

Here's what the soil looks like.
[image]

The techniques I've come across for removing grass are

1. removing the sod and replacing the lost matter with compost
2. smothering the area with cardboard and with mulch on top

(2) seems like a better idea because with (1) I'm concerned about the loss of organic matter and whether I'll be able to replace it and because it's labor intensive. Furthermore, with (1) I'm unsure whether I'll be able to plant immediately even if I do replace the top soil

With the smothering technique I plan on making holes in the paper and planting seeds. What I've read, though, is that people use this technique for planting potted plants. Will this technique work with growing plants from seeds?

Comment: Tell us about the light available, no point in planting vegetables if you dont have good thick soil and lots of light

Comment: It has plenty of sunlight and the grass roots are 3 in deep.

Comment: Only three inches deep? Hmm. Do you have clay, sand, silt, or loam soil? How deep is the topsoil?

Comment: I'm not sure how to classify the soil, but I've added a picture of it.

Comment: Step zero - make sure you are not subject to an HOA with obnoxious rules that forbid this. I wish I was kidding - I'm not.

Comment: You could just dig up the sod, in chunks, turn it over and let dry out. Then mix it up again. Or rototill it.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx would that get rid of the weeds in the old sod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with "I want to plant immediately" is that the grass and roots need time to break down, and while they will ultimately provide nutrients (when broken down) they tie up a good deal of the nutrients while breaking down. Thus, those nutrients won't be available to your new plants for some time.

The classic means to turn sod into soil is to invert it (whether by ploughing or by using a sodcutter and flipping it) or to pile it in heaps to compost (with the resulting material being "loam" in the classic sense.) Both would better have been done last year if you want to plant now.

There are a number of folks who strongly disagree with the idea of covering the soil surface with sheet cardboard, as it tends to kill off the aerobic soil bacteria by suffocation. There are also plenty of sources that continue to recommend it.

Probably the best bet if you wish to plant now would be to buy **quite a bit** of compost, use a sodcutter to cut strips for your beds, leaving the paths as grass for now, and pile the cut sod to rot down for use later. Put the compost in your bed areas, and try to plan the rest of your garden project a bit further in advance. Size the grass paths to suit what you have for a small lawnmower, and they will be simpler to keep mown. Grass paths are good for not getting muddy, usually. You may need to edge them regularly to keep them from growing into your beds. This is quite common in the UK and uncommon in the USA for some reason. (I'm from the states and visit friends in the UK, and look at their gardens.)

Comment: "pile the cut sod to rot down for use later": do you mean this could be used for compost? Also, compost is a bit expensive. Is it OK if I replace the matter with a mix of (bought) topsoil and compost?

Comment: Your first question is answered in the second paragraph. The second will depend on the quality of the "topsoil" available for you to buy.

Comment: FYI, besides indeed killing the life in the soil, cardboard has also been found to contain a number of environmental toxins, including PCBs and PFAS. See here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37245822/.